# Updating gridview row is not saving the data

Tags: asp.net

I am having issue when updating gridview! everything is seems to be working. but when i hit finish editing the data will not save!

but when i click edit the correct fields prompt me to enter new value but it wont save!

here is my asp

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="report" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
    DataKeyNames="TimeID" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
    onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">

    <Columns> 



        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" Visible="true" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Stage Description" ReadOnly="True" />


       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"  Text='<%# ConvertToShotTime(Eval("StartTime")) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" ValidationGroup="1" Width="90px"  class="TimeEntry" runat="server"  Text='<%# ConvertToShotTime(Eval("StartTime")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" ControlToValidate="txtStartTime" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>




        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Time">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text='<%# ConvertToShotTime(Eval("EndTime")) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndTime" class="TimeEntry"  ValidationGroup="1" Width="90px" runat="server"  Text='<%# ConvertToShotTime(Eval("EndTime")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator66" ControlToValidate="txtEndTime" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>



        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeInHours" HeaderText="Time Time (Hours)" ReadOnly="True" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" 
            ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit_record.jpg" 
            CancelImageUrl="~/images/edit_no.jpg" 
            UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update_record.jpg" />

        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="lnbCopy" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" 
                    CommandName="DeleteRecord"  CommandArgument='<%# Bind("TimeID") %>'  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?');"  ImageUrl="~/images/delete_record.jpg" />
            </ItemTemplate>

           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TimeID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>









    </Columns>


</asp:GridView>
```

here is what i have done in behind code

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) {
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    loadTable();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e) {
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    loadTable();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) {

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;


    var StartTime = row.FindControl("txtStartTime") as TextBox;
    var EndTime = row.FindControl("txtEndTime") as TextBox;
    var id = row.FindControl("lblTimeID") as Label;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr.GetConnectionString("myServer1"));

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

    comm.CommandText = "UPDATE CDSTimeSheet SET StartTime = @StartTime, EndTime = @EndTime ,timeElapsed = datediff(minute,@startTime , @EndTime), timeInSeconds = datediff(second,@startTime , @EndTime) WHERE TimeID = @id";
    comm.Connection = conn;

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", StartTime.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", EndTime.Text);

    conn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    loadTable();
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you receiving any error? Try to debug and checkout update statement whether id is getting passed..

Comment: no no errors at all. it seems like it is doing like a canel even insted on edit!

Comment: Can you show your `loadTable()` function?  Are you calling `GridView1.DataBind()` in there?

Comment: Also: double check the underlying data (using SQL Server Management Studio or something) to make sure that your update really is successful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like you are not calling `DataBind` on your grid after updating the underlying data.  After you perform the update (possibly within the `loadTable` method that I see referenced up there), call

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

That should refresh the data in the grid.

---

After your comments, I see that you're not using the `NewValues` collection in the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` parameter to get the actual incoming, updated field values.  Try this:

```
String StartTime = e.NewValues["StartTime"].ToString();
String EndTime = e.NewValues["EndTime"].ToString();
String id = e.Keys[0].ToString();
```

Note that these variables are strings now, not `TextBox`s, so you don't need to add ".Text" on them when you add them as parameters.

Comment: Yes I have gridview1.bind in my loadTable.   Infact load table works perfectly and also I have a remove that is working fine! Also to test to make sure the correct function is called when edit is triggered I printed a test on the screen and it work! But the update is not beeing executed! I don't have my code infront of me so I can't post my load table function

Comment: Is it at all possible, @user1915046, that your `WHERE` clause is causing no rows to be updated?  For your test cases, if you run that `UPDATE` statement as a `SELECT` statement, do you get any results?  (e.g. run `SELECT * FROM CDSTimeSheet WHERE TimeID = 12345`)

Comment: so here is the problem        var StartTime = row.FindControl("txtStartTime") as TextBox;
    var EndTime = row.FindControl("txtEndTime") as TextBox;
    var id = row.FindControl("lblTimeID") as Label; return the same sada that is initialy selected!   so the info is updated with the same information! how can i get the new data?

Comment: @user1915046 I can't believe I didn't notice that!  You need to use the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` object that's passed to your RowUpdating method.  Specifically, pull the values out of the "NewValues" collection.

Comment: I am sorry but can you be more clear on that? I mean where do i user GridViewUpdateEventArgs and how if possible?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Handle the postback, basically if you fill the grid view in each postback you are re filling the gridview with old data, that's why you retrieve data with no changes (remember after Update button this trigger a postback). So, in case this is your case, try this.

```
if(!this.IsPostback)
{
    (Method that fills your GridView)
}
```